# Shopify Storage Redis Issue with Node React App

Tags: redis, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api-node

I have added session storage in serve.js as follows :-

```
import SessionHandler from "./SessionHandler";
const sessionStorage = new SessionHandler();

Shopify.Context.initialize({
  API_KEY: process.env.SHOPIFY_API_KEY,
  API_SECRET_KEY: process.env.SHOPIFY_API_SECRET,
  SCOPES: process.env.SCOPES.split(","),
  HOST_NAME: process.env.HOST.replace(/https:\/\//, ""),
  API_VERSION: ApiVersion.October21,
  IS_EMBEDDED_APP: false,
  // This should be replaced with your preferred storage strategy
  //SESSION_STORAGE: new Shopify.Session.MemorySessionStorage(),
  SESSION_STORAGE: new Shopify.Session.CustomSessionStorage(
    sessionStorage.storeCallback,
    sessionStorage.loadCallback,
    sessionStorage.deleteCallback
  ),
});
```

My router get function is

```
router.get("(.*)", async (ctx) => {
    const shop = ctx.query.shop;
    let documentQuery = { shop: shop };
    let data = await SessionStorage.findOne(documentQuery);   //this finds the store in the session table
    if (ACTIVE_SHOPIFY_SHOPS[shop] === undefined) {
      if (data == null) {
        ctx.redirect(`/auth?shop=${shop}`);
      } else {
        await handleRequest(ctx);
      }
    } else {
      await handleRequest(ctx);
    }
  });
```

and than in the SessionHandler file added code as attached in file ,
but when I run install the app it goes to the storeCallback , loadcallback and deletecallback function multiple times

[StoreCallback Function Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5cHN.png)

[Load and delete callback function code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Atacz.png)

Answer (score 0):

sorry I have edited my answer as I think its incorrect . all I can say for now is to look at this example:https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-api-node/blob/main/docs/usage/customsessions.md
if you havent already..